# Google Cloud Messaging changes to registration process

Tags: php, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Last week Google Cloud Messaging introduced Instance Id's and Token Id's.

I am wondering if anyone has attempted to decipher the new arrangement.

If so, and I know these are basic questions, but can you please tell me:

1. the GCM url I use to obtain instance id's and token id's;
2. whether I still require a registration id [from my reading it appears not];
3. If I submit a string to the GCM url to retrieve this information what is the required syntax - or, alternatively, what is the required syntax in php;

I look forward to your assistance.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. You get instance ID and token on the client, using a library; I don't think they expose a URL for this.  Since you've included the android tag I will assume your client is Android, so [here is the reference](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/iid/InstanceID) for the API's to do what you want.  Note that these are implemented in Google Play Services 7.5.
2. It seems that you now need a token retrieved on the client with GCM authorization.
3. Not sure exactly what you mean by this (and I don't know PHP) but I think the server side API/syntax should remain the same other then that you use the new token instead of the old registration ID, and there are some new features (eg. sending to topics).  The details [are here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server).

Comment: Thank you Tom. I am venturing down the php path using the technique others have used on this forum. I assume as others start to use instance id and token id the picture will become clearer